# It's possible trigger a event when all templates and data are loaded

Tags: angularjs

It's possible trigger a event when all templates and data are loaded. I have a application made with AngularJS, is finished it but on the production server i have a problem. When a page is loaded the templates are loaded and showed but  some times the data comes later and show the elements empty for a while 1~3 seconds (internet connection issues, bandwidth, server load, etc.).

It's possible trigger a event when all is loaded (templates, data, etc.) for show a message loading and hide when the event is fired?

My question is something that can be generally applied as a page can have X amount of directives and these can load additional data

Answer (score 0):

**[This is only a partial solution]**

Some delays are due to templates loading with, `ng-include`.

In your `.run` you could collect all the `ng-include`s with and wait for all of them to finish:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
   var loadingIncludeCount = 0;
   $rootScope.isLoading = function(){ return loadingIncludeCount > 0; }

   $rootScope.$on("$includeContentRequested", function(){ loadingIncludeCount ++; });
   $rootScope.$on("$includeContentLoaded",    function(){ loadingIncludeCount --; });
   $rootScope.$on("$includeContentError",     function(){ loadingIncludeCount --; });
}
```

This would NOT solve for directives loading their `templateUrl`s.